# why my subquery is not executing?

Tags: mysql

I am going to Work with Sub queries in mysql, the question is when I am trying to execute it, i got this error, it should be mention that my column names are correct.

```
 Error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
 the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
 right syntax to use near 'Products Â Â Â Â Â WHERE 
 productLine In Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  (SELECT text' at line 2

SELECT ProductName, buyPrice
     FROM Products
     WHERE productLine In 
             (SELECT textDescription
             FROM productline
             WHERE productLine = "Motorcycles");
```

Comment: You want `'Motorcycles'`.  Single quote, not double.

Comment: I tried with single quote as well, not working

Comment: is there any registries with `productLine = 'Motorcycles'` ?? Maybe you are getting some casesensitive problem. Try to run `SELECT textDescription FROM productline` and see if it exists indeed.

Comment: Break it down then.  Try each select separately, see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: Also... did you use some copy paste text from another place? The error  states there are some enconding problem. Try to type instead of paste

Comment: @Andrew: by default, single quotes and double quotes do the same thing in MySQL (this is different from SQL Server). See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @user3024597 if you add [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your problem it would be easier to resolve

Comment: Which types are productLine  and textDescription fields?

Comment: I tried select queries separately, they are working, maybe the problems is in (IN)